# How to make a proxy redirect traffic to the nearest cluster with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

Good day, I own a cluster set in Peru, Spain and the United States, and in each one I have a web cluster, I would like to know if there is a way for these clusters to prepend a Proxy or Load Balancer that according to the user's connection send it to closest cluster and so are able to obtain your data queries locally.

I would like to know if anyone who knows a way to do this can help me, if it can be done with nodejs or it is only through configurations in the router.

I remain attentive to your comments, thank you in advance.